# Regex usage in grep

Tags: regex, bash, grep

Im trying to search for a pattern in a file as follows:

```
SRC_ERROR_CODE=105
SRC_ERROR_CODE=106
...
```

To achieve this following is the grep statement used:

```
grep -io "[a-z]*_error_code=[0-9]*" events.log
```

However i was wondering if instead of using the "*" which fetches 0 to n occurrences of the preceding matched character, the "+" should fetch the same results as well as below:

```
grep -io "[a-z]+_error_code=[0-9]+" events.log
```

But, this doesn't seem to work.
Could you please guide as to why it doesn't.

Thanks

Comment: Im not sure what your question is.   `+` will select 1 to N occurrences, and unless specified is greedy in terms of finding matches.  I think you need to give more information.  Why doesnt it work?  Is it returning the wrong set, or is it returning an error, or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In POSIX Basic Regular Expressions (BRE), the default regex dialect used by `grep`, `+` just matches itself.

In POSIX Extended Regular Expressions (ERE) and Perl Compatible RegEx (PCRE), `+` matches 1 or more of the preceding atom.

You can ask `grep` to use ERE with the `-E` option:

```
$ echo "foo baaar" | grep -o -E 'a+'
aaa
```

Answer (score 0):

The `+` in regex matches one or more character in Extended Regular Expression (ERE - this is egrep)

In Basic regular expression (BRE) you have to escape the `+` sign.

Since you are using `grep`, you have to escape the `+`. Therefore, use `\+` instead of `+`.

If you are using `egrep`, you can use the unescaped `+`

Comment: These days, `egrep` is just an (effective) alias for `grep -E` (similarly, `fgrep` maps onto `grep -F`). For long-term POSIX compliance it's better to use `grep` with options. While both BSD `grep` and GNU `grep` do support `\+` in BREs, it's important to note that `\+` in BREs is _not_ POSIX-compliant and other tools, such as `sed` on BSD-like platforms, do _not_ support it; the POSIX-compliant equivalent of the `+` ERE construct is the - somewhat cumbersome - `\{1,\}`.